# Is it possible to run a hybrid pc on drastically low power consumption while still displaying a slideshow?

Tags: process, power-management, images, x-server

I've bought a Surface Pro 3 for my elders, and installed ZorinOS on it -- a great distro for hybrid pcs btw!!

One stuff we'd like it to do is to act as a digital photo-frame by running a slideshow of the family pictures, but I'm concerned with the amount of energy needed to power this piece of hardware just to have a slideshow running on the shelf.

#### Question

--> I'm wondering if there is a way to drastically reduce the power consumption of that computer by killing every task not needed to run the slideshow, while still being able to reset things properly when needed?

*I managed once to run GUIs without a DE on a RPi4 running DietPi, bu I don't know if it's relevant here*

**e.g.:** case 1) the computer is on display, keyboard detached, and runs on low-power, photo-frame mode only; case 2) the computer is placed on a table to be used in a regular way.

So I'd need a toggle between the two states.

#### Informations

- Surface Pro 3
- Operating System: Zorin OS 16.1
- Kernel: Linux 5.18.10-surface
- Architecture: x86-64
- image viewer : **[qView](https://interversehq.com/qview/)**

#### Other resort

I've got two RPis 4 in the drawer that could be turned into a digital photo-frame with low power consumption in case what I was imagining with the hybrid pc isn't relevant.

Comment: What is a hybrid PC?,  (a hybrid of what) and how does it relate?

Comment: tablet-pc --> like microsoft surface pro or Wacom's mobile studio (= a fully functionnal pc in a tablet form factor with touch capability).

Comment: I don't think the hybrid nature will affect things. So yes. If this does not answer you question, then remove irrelevant data, and add it to the end of the question (just in case). You have already done the latter.